# Design system with tailwind

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, build, monorepo

I developed a design system using tailwind and storybook (https://github.com/RicardoBrito1938/monorepo-design-system)

After i published on NPM, to consume this design system in other react/next js app i need to make a tailwind configuration, you will in this repo that i have a configuration with Stiches too, my tailwind components work when i make a configuration and import the css styles from the library, but i would like to see if there is a more independent way of doing that, is it something that i can add in my build?

i tried to chaange and add some dependencies to my package.json but no success, i would like the library be ready to use in any react/next js without the tailwind configuration at the consumer side